# Excell vba error 400 endless loop

Tags: vba, stack, infinite-loop

I have been writing on a VBA code that executes calculations on a steel portal structure in an external program.

The steel portal structure consists of 2 columns and 1 beam. 
For the first calculation, the dimensions and loads are entered, for the following calculations the VBA code will first automatically change the steel profiles and repeat the calculation.

After each calculation in the external program, the results are loaded in excell. The results will then be written on a sheet "Resume". For each calculation there are 6 cells (column profile, beam profile, unity check column, unity check beam, deformation column,...).

*After the construction is calculated for a number of different profiles, the "resume" sheet will be saved as a new sheet (named als "Length beam, column height, portal distance"). After that, sheet "resume" will be cleared, dimensions (length and portal distance) are changed and the calculation will start again saving each result on the empty "resume" sheet.

Each resume sheet contains about 300 calculations and must be repeated for 14 different column heights and 6 portal distances (total 84 sheets, 25200 calculations).

The calculation is based on 2 sub procedures.

Sub BerekenSpant() (E: Sub CalculateResults())
Sub ControleerResultaat () (E: Sub EvaluateResults())

Sub BerekenSpant() works fine. This sub creates the XML file for the external calculation program and imports the results after calculation.

Sub ControleerResultaat() also works fine (for about 150 calculations). This sub uses the results imported by BerekenSpant() and writes them in the "Resume" sheet. Then it compares changes the steel column (or beam, or beam and column) and calls Sub "BerekenSpant()" again. After 300 calculations (after the final beam and column combination is calculated) the portal length is adjusted and * is executed.

So Sub ControleerResultaat() will actually never be ended (untill 25200 calculations are performed). This causes a stack overload I guess... If I restart the calculations after the "400" fault is given, again 150 calculations are performed without problems...

How can I solve this problem so the calculation isn't interrupted each 150 calculations?

Thank you for your answers!

Last part of the code in "ControleerResultaat()":

```
    If HuidigeKolom = EindKolom And HuidigeDakligger = EindDakligger Then
    If Worksheets("TABEL").Cells(RijHoogteHal, 2).Value <= 11.5 Then 
        Dim NieuweH As Double
        NieuweH = (HSpanttemp + 0.5)
        Worksheets("TABEL").Cells(RijHoogteHal, 2).Value = NieuweH 'Nieuwe hoogte toewijzen voor nieuwe berekening
        Worksheets("TABEL").Cells(RijProfielKolommen, 2).Value = StartKolom
        Worksheets("TABEL").Cells(RijProfielDakligger, 2).Value = StartDakligger
        'Tabblad combinaties opslaan, hernoemen en tabblad combinaties leegmaken voor volgende berekening
        Sheets("Combinaties").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets("Combinaties (2)").Name = "L= " & LSpanttemp & " m, H= " & HSpanttemp & " m, D= " & Spantafstand
        Sheets("Combinaties").Range("B5:CZ52").ClearContents
        BerekenSpant
        ControleerResultaat

    ElseIf Worksheets("TABEL").Cells(RijDeltaSpant, 2).Value <= 8 Then 'tot maximaal 8m spantafstand de berekening uitvoeren
        NieuweTA = (Spantafstand + 0.5)
        Worksheets("TABEL").Cells(RijHoogteHal, 2).Value = 5 'Spanthoogte opnieuw instellen op startwaarde 5m
        Worksheets("TABEL").Cells(RijDeltaSpant, 2).Value = NieuweTA
        Worksheets("TABEL").Cells(RijProfielKolommen, 2).Value = StartKolom
        Worksheets("TABEL").Cells(RijProfielDakligger, 2).Value = StartDakligger
        'Tabblad combinaties opslaan, hernoemen en tabblad combinaties leegmaken voor volgende berekening
        Sheets("Combinaties").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets("Combinaties (2)").Name = "L= " & LSpanttemp & " m, H= " & HSpanttemp & " m, D= " & Spantafstand
        Sheets("Combinaties").Range("B5:CZ52").ClearContents
        BerekenSpant
        ControleerResultaat
    Else
        MsgBox ("Klaar met berekening!")
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You'll need to show your code in order for us to help you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: your question is `my VBA code gets an error code 400 every 150 calculations`  ... the rest of your question text is meaningless because you have not posted any code

Comment: Thank you for the response. However I cannot post the complete code because it's protected. Anyway the question that summarizes the problem: 

Is it a "Visual basic limited" problem or code based problem? Sub "ControleerResultaat()" keeps calling "Berekenspant()" and itself untill the 25200 calculations are over. 

Part of the code has been added.